# IntelliJ IDEA contract for not null return value

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use @contract Java annotation in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5
But in this case it seems not working:

```
private String name;

void setName(String name) {
    this.name = null;     // for test
}

@Contract("-> !null")
String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

Is it possible to resolve this problem?

Thank you for any reply!

Comment: What is it exactly you want to achieve with this contract ?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Contract("-> !null")` is on the method `getName`. That means when you call `getName` in a conditional comparison to `null`, IntelliJ will warn you the condition is always false and offer to simplify the code. In your example, there's no calls to `getName`, so there's no visible effect.

```
public class A {
    @Contract("-> !null")
    String getName() {
        return "jimmy";
    }

    void method() {
        if (getName() == null) { // for test
            System.out.println("null");
        }
    }
}
```

If you mean to have IntelliJ to warn you if `null` is attempted to be assigned to the variable `name`, use the `@NotNull` annotation on the field.

```
public class A {
    @NotNull private String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.name = null;
    }
}
```